# Interstitial ad with load delay

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I'm trying to implement an interstitial ad, and I'd like it to load before, in the application it's happening to load along with the action which causes delay and makes the ad appear well after. I want to make the ad appear right after pressing "adicionar" as shown in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHxkT.png)

The code below shows how it was implemented:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8920922366585510/4181958830");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        if (requestCode == ADD_PACK) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                if (data != null) {
                    final String validationError = data.getStringExtra("validation_error");
                    if (validationError != null) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            //validation error should be shown to developer only, not users.
                            MessageDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.title_validation_error, validationError).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "validation error");
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "Validation failed:" + validationError);
                    }
                } else {
                    new StickerPackNotAddedMessageFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "sticker_pack_not_added");
                }
            }
        }
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded()  {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I've tried loading the call before these codes but I can not load before.

```
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8920922366585510/4181958830");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

The application is an open source github, the link is below if you want to download to see the complete code and help: [DOWNLOAD COMPLETE CODE](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/Android)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into your `onCreate` method:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8920922366585510/4181958830");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

And put the following into your `onActivityResult`:

```
if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
   mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and of course I didn't wanted to load the ad on activity creation, so I decided to load the ad on at the same moment the dialog opens, have the "adicionar" button disabled and when the ad was loaded then enable the button.

I also decided to add a description to wait on the button to be enabled.

This might not be the solution you are looking for but at least is the most optimal on data loading. Hope it helps!

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: In the method I launched the dialog I also call  the loading of the ad. I don't have my code available now but it as something like this: - create dialog with disabled button. - load ad. - enable the button onAdLoaded(). - open ad when button is clicked

Comment: I can next week, hope is not too late. Ill post it as an answer